# Using regexp_like

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

I have a query where I am using `regex_like`, and I need more than one parameter, something like this:

```
WHERE regexp_like (FILENAME,'_G_',) or (FILENAME,'_Z_',) or (FILENAME,'_M_',)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need  multiple conditions to do this with `like`, but `regexp_like` lets you use a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) which is a more flexible type of search pattern.

Answer (score 3):

You can factorize the regexp as follows:

```
WHERE regexp_like (FILENAME,'_[GMZ]_',)
```

`[GMZ]` represents a custom character class made of characters `'G'`, `'M'` and `'Z'`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `regexp`:

```
regexp_like (FILENAME,'.{1}[GZM]{1}.{1}')
```

- Here `.` (dot) represents any character
- `{1}` represents only 1 character is allowed for the preceding pattern.

Cheers!!

Comment: There is actually no need for the `{1}`  quantifier here, it is implicit when not specified. Also, `'_'` (a litteral underscore) and `.` (any character) are two different things.

Comment: Yes, I know about `_` and `.` but I think OP is comparing `LIKE` and `REGEXP_LIKE`.  In `LIKE` underscore `_` means any character so I used `.`

Comment: Thank you so much and can i order by the it , like :
Parameter     Year    sell 
N                    2009   444
G                    2009   555
M                    2009    6666
F                     2010    77

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add two or more different parameters, that do not have a lots in common, then you can use `|` to separate them like this:

```
select * 
from table_name 
WHERE regexp_like (FILENAME,'_G_|-kk_|-AH-');
```

Here is a small [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=028e081f86ec7a93f4ad6ca8a2f57ca9)

Do not know what exactly you want when you ask to "order by it" but try this:

```
select id, filename
from table_name 
WHERE regexp_like (FILENAME,'_G_|-kk_|-AH-')
order by filename
```

Comment: Thank you so much for ur very fast answer

Thank you so much and can i order by the it , like : 
Parameter Year sell 
N 2009 444 
G 2009 555 
M 2009 6666 
F 2010 77